# Does newest LCC-win64 support ISO C99 standard math library?

Tags: c, c99, lcc

A while back, LCC did not support C99: e.g. if I use math functions, such as "sinf", "acosh", it did not work.

I have heard that they have been adding support for C99 in the last few years.

Does anyone know whether the latest support C99 ISO? Is there a place where I may find the information?

Thanks!

Comment: The [changelog](https://lcc-win32.services.net/README) makes no mention of it

Comment: You might consider [Pelles C](https://www.pellesc.de/index.php?page=overview&lang=en); it was based on LCC, and claims to support most of C99 (with at least some support for C11).